# How to use User-Managed Identity from Azure Cloud Function (python) in making a request to Azure KeyVault?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity, azure-function-app

My current Setup:

My DevOps guy has created a User Managed Identity and have added it to the Access policy of Azure key Vault.
I have Created a function app `testing-01` and assigned the User-ManagedIdentity to it under platform settings.
I am using Python 3.6 as runtime language.

This is my helper method that i use to check if i am able to access the secrets from key vault.
and i am returning its response.

```
def cred_checker():
    credential = ManagedIdentityCredential()
    # credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id='client_id 
    vault_name= "myvault"
    client = SecretClient(vault_url=f"https://{vault_name}.vault.azure.net/", credential=credential)
    username = client.get_secret(name="username")
    password= client.get_secret(name="password")

    return f"AKV client created successfully {client} .<br> name: {username},<br> pass: {password} "
```

I am able to create the client with no error. But when i try to fetch secret from it, I am getting this ClientAuthenticationError :

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerFunc <--- Result: Failure Exception: ClientAuthenticationError: Unexpected response '{'statusCode': 400, 'message': 'Unable to load requested managed identity.', 'correlationId': '92daf146-fed2-4a75-8359-9r955939815e'}'
```

Answer (score 5):

When you use a user-assigned identity, you need to specify the [`client_id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.managedidentitycredential?view=azure-python-preview#parameters) of the MSI in [`ManagedIdentityCredential()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.managedidentitycredential?view=azure-python-preview).

```
credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id="xxxxxxxx")
```

To get the `client_id`, navigate to your function app -> `Identity` -> `User assigned` -> click your user-assigned identity -> copy the `client_id`.

[image]

Comment: I have tried this approach also, If you see the comment(python comment) in my function. It did not worked.

Comment: For anyone who is using the "DefaultAzureCredential" class instead of the "ManagedIdentityCredential" class, this also applies, passing the "client_Id" of your user-managed identity as a keyword argument. Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would use Managed Identity in python:

```
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import MSIAuthentication
creds = MSIAuthentication()
client = SecretClient(vault_url=MyVaultUrl, credentials=creds)
```

For this to work however, you have to have the identity assigned to your azure function as part of the deployment. If you are using terraform, there is a provider which you can use and it accepts an identity {} block where you can specify type="UserAssigned" and identity_ids = ["id1", "id2",...]

Comment: I guess this is not working anymore `Error.Unsupported credential: <msrestazure.azure_active_directory.MSIAuthentication object at 0x7ee9b4b5a230>`